# mkbundle error 32512: no package mono-2

Tags: linux, aws, mono

I'm trying to generate a static bundle using `mkbundle --static file.exe -o file --i18n none`, but I get the following output:

```
Package mono-2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mono-2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mono-2' found
Package mono-2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mono-2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mono-2' found
Package mono-2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mono-2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mono-2' found
sh: cc: command not found
ERROR: [Fail] 32512
```

(I added --i18n none to avoid "i18n.dll not found" error)
I'm running on an Amazon AWS server. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm also running into this problem. Did you ever find a workaround? If it helps, I'm trying to wrap an executable in mono that's quite old (a boogie executable from 2012).